# HTML5-Canvas active framework for fast robust simple use

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've just received a request from a client to build a website which I guess needs HTML5 canvas to be deployed. For you to have an idea it is a kind of train with different cars. Visitor should be able to scroll left and right along the train and click on the windows to show different contents (in a pop up or stand alone window).

I'm quite new to Canvas but feel comfortable with HTML, CSS and javascript/jQuery, so I believe I could give it a try. I'd love to know though whether there's an **active (maintained as for 2017) canvas framework to start from** for the before mentioned needs. *I've already checked around i SO but replies go back to 2012 with answers recommending outdated/unmaintained libraries.* A good complete gallery of samples would do too.

It should work both on computer and mobile OSs.

TIA. Have a nice day,
hip

or a reliant to start from

Comment: There is no reason to use canvas though

Comment: You can totally do this without canvas, canvas would just complicate things here.

Comment: Here is an interesting example of things that can be done with html/js/css: http://www.artofflightmovie.com/

Comment: Ty all. I'll give it a look. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily doable without canvas, some animation libraries like GSAP.

You can design an SVG for the train , and make it scroll left or right inside a div as per mouse or touch-input, and handle all the animation using GSAP

though, I'd recommend Fabric.js for canvas based events and animations.

Comment: Train is an image. Everything's been 'designed by graphic designers' so there's nice bitmap images for every single detail, even animations of the train windows opening... So no SVG for what I believe. I'll check GSAP and/or some javascript scroll plugins I've found. Ty